# JIRA service Desk Test environment

Tags: jira

We are using JIRA Software and JIRA Service Desks in our company.
I am new to JIRA and i want to ask if it is possible to create a test environment for a few projects or service desks? If yes, how can i set it up ?

Mfg

Comment: Only few projects or you want to create a staging instance similar to your production?

Comment: if it is possible a similar instance. But for my work i need to do changes on the service desks ( we have 4 ) only.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in https://pm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, JIRA ServiceDesk is a Plugin in JIRA and it uses AO Tables. With that said, JIRA Project Export and Import doesn't support Exporting AO Tables. It means that you are not able to import ServiceDesk Projects to the other instances. You can take a look at their feature request [here](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSDSERVER-2741).

Thus, I would say it's better to clone the full production instance into a test environment. In order to do that, you have to create backup from home directory, installation directory and database and restore them into a test instance. Full steps are available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/establishing-staging-server-environments-for-jira-applications-802592273.html) in Atlassian Documentations.

Please note that, prior to start the staging environment you have to disable incoming and outgoing emails with the available JVM Arguments. Otherwise, new issues will create in your test servers instead of production.